# why does the cooldown on my gun not work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this gun that's supposed to have a cooldown after every shot by using `time between shots += Time.deltaTime`. The problem is that it's like `timeBeetweenShots` dosen't increase. Here's the part of my code that I think matters:

```
 private void Update()
    {
        timeSinceLastShot += Time.deltaTime;
    }

       public bool CanShoot() => !gunData.reloading && timeSinceLastShot > 1 / (gunData.fireRate / 60);

    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (gunData.currentAmmo > 0)
        {
            if (CanShoot())
            {
                Debug.Log("shooting");
                gunData.currentAmmo--;
                timeSinceLastShot = 0;
                OnGunShot();
            }
        } else
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reload());
        }
    }
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Where are timeBeetweenShots? I don't know at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think we might need to use [Time.time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html).

The doc link is just perfect for gun fire interval.

However I had edit your code.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    GunData gunData; // gundata might be access from player
    float timeSinceLastShot = 0;
    private void Update()
    {

    }
    public bool CanShoot() => !gunData.reloading && (timeSinceLastShot + gunData.fireRate) < Time.time;

    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (gunData.currentAmmo > 0)
        {
            if (CanShoot())
            {
                Debug.Log("shooting");
                gunData.currentAmmo--;
                timeSinceLastShot = Time.time;// save the last time that shot
                OnGunShot();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reload());
        }
    }
    public void OnGunShot()
    { // animation might be here
    }
    IEnumerator Reload()
    {   // relaoding might be here
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); 
    }
}

public class GunData // just dummy data 
{
    public int currentAmmo = 10;
    public float fireRate = 0.2f;
    public bool reloading = false;
}
```

Comment: the canshoot bool still dosen't work. it spawns projectiles when I remove the bool, but not when its on.